# inertia js Laravel and vue 3

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

i have made project using inertia js my problem is with the side bar tree, it should be three level Merchant the customers then the rest but when i click on merchant the page is loading and the side tree bar appear and disappear in same time i tried to safe it in local storage but still not working

i want the tree stage to be working properly when i click in merchant in will only show customers in the side bar and the page will be load on the meddle and when you click on the customers it will show the rest of the side bar, i don't want the side bar to disappear when the page is loading
[

```
const navItems = [
{ href: "#",label:"Merchant", children:[
        {href: "#", label:"Customers", children:[

        {href: "#", label:"Transactions", children:[]},
        {href: "#", label:"Rewards", children:[]},
        {href: "#", label:"Organization", children:[]},
        {href: "#", label:"Estore", children:[]},
        {href: "#", label:"Billing", children:[]},

        ]},
        
]},
];
]
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Onzn.png)